# What is best apprach to attempt multiple times same RPC call

Tags: gwt, rpc

What is best way to attempt multiple time same RPC call while failing RPC call?

just example: Here one case like if RPC get failed due to network connection,  it will catch in  `onFailure(Throwable caught)`. 
Now here it should recall same RPC again for check network connection. The maximum attempt should be 3 times only then show message to user like "Network is not established"
How can I achieve it?

Some couple of thoughts like call same rpc call in `onFailure` but here request become different.but I want `same request have a three request` and it is not good approach and I don't know if any good solution for it.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter in your `AsynCallBack` implementation. I recommend as well to use a timer before requesting the server again.

This code should work:

```java
  final GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);
  final String textToServer = "foo";
  greetingService.greetServer(textToServer, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
    int tries = 0;
    public void onSuccess(String result) {
      // Do something
    }
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
      if (tries ++ < 3) {
        // Optional Enclose the new call in a timer to wait sometime before requesting the server again
        new Timer() {
          public void run() {
            greetingService.greetServer(textToServer, this);
          }
        }.schedule(4000);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, It works +1 and I got other good way for implement it from Google Group. so I share that answer also.

Answer (score 0):

@Jens given this answer from Google Groups.

You could transparently handle this for all your requests of a given GWT-RPC interface by using a custom RpcRequestBuilder. This custom RpcRequestBuilder would make 3 request attempts and if all 3 fail, calls the onFailure() method.

> MyRemoteServiceAsync service = GWT.create(MyRemoteService.class);
>   ((ServiceDefTarget) service).setRpcRequestBuilder(new RetryThreeTimesRequestBuilder());

The custom RequestBuilder could also fire a "NetworkFailureEvent" on the eventBus if multiple application components may be interested in that information. For example you could overlay the whole app with a dark screen and periodically try sending Ping requests to your server until network comes back online. There is also the onLine HTML 5 property you can check, but its not 100% reliable (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.onLine)